# Why won't my 1 TB USB drive appear?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, hard-drive

I've been having some problems with getting an USB drive to appear. First I connected it to my Ubuntu laptop and the drive appeared and I could format it with the ext file system. Then I moved the drive to another computer that is also running Ubuntu and the drive won't appear in GParted or other tools. Could you recommend a way to proceed? Thanks

UPDATE. Here's the output from `$ dmesg | tail`

```
[245126.162668] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245128.122950] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245128.186959] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245128.554783] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245129.050730] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245132.522971] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245132.578123] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245133.466497] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245134.627949] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245135.574092] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while hiding cursor
```

...

```
[257116.514694] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-6:1.0
[257117.545565] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       5000AAKB Externa l108 P
Q: 0 ANSI: 0
[257117.546254] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[257117.549423] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465
 GiB)
[257117.550426] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[257117.550430] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[257117.551416] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[257117.551422] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[257117.554039] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[257117.554043] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[257117.557055]  sdc: sdc1
[257117.559543] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page present
[257117.559548] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[257117.559552] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

And new output from `$dmesg | tail`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | tail
[  128.502416] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[  130.703847] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[  130.703909] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[  130.703935] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[  135.755667] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[11469.094303] EXT4-fs (sdc1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: did you unmount the drive first before moving the drive?

Comment: Not sure. I'm still investigating this. The drive neither appears in ubuntu nor ms-windows

Comment: is it one of these Western Digital disks that you have security enabled via "My Passport"? - you may need to run it to unlock the drive via MS Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is LaCie 1 TB that I now connected to MS_Windows XP to see how it appears. Either Linux or MS-Windows should be able to get some contact.

Comment: If you've formatted with ext then Windows should think that its unformatted and ask to format it.  If it doesnt, possibly a faulty drive?  Can you force mount it (see my answer)?

Comment: It used to work and was ext3 (I think.) It worked in january. Now I can't mount it. sdc1 was already mounted. Should I choose some other destination instead? `/dev/sdc1 already mounted`

Comment: Those msgs (above) are a separate kernel bug relating to graphics & mouse 245126.162668] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245128.122950] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor
[245128.186959] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: no space while unhiding cursor

Comment: According to your dmesg, the drive is only 500 gb, not 1tb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you force mounting of the drive?

```
sudo mkdir /media/LaCie
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /media/LaCie -o force
```

A couple of pointers - ext4 is the drive format - if you formatted with ext2 or 3 then use "ext2" or "ext3" respectively.

Also "/dev/sdc1" is the device name linux sees your drive.  You can see what device name is by running `dmesg`.

N.B. check that the drive is being seen - first boot without your drive - run `dmesg` - plug in your drive and run `dmesg` again.

If no output is displayed - then my strong guess is that you have a defective drive.

Your question had some initial `dmesg` trace - if you no longer have any output then my strong guess was that your drive was dying - and now has died.

Similarly - if Windows does not offer to format the drive when it is plugged in, this is another strong indicator that the drive has failed.

As to why - external drives are like other drives - if you moved/bumped the drive whilst in use it could cause corruptions.  In rare causes - cause it to fail.

Drives are mechanical - any sort of weak mechanical link/electrical failure would cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Trying: `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc1 /media/LaCie -o force`  `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
`

Comment: did you format the drive ext2/3 or 4 - obviously change the `ext4` filetype appropriately.  also - anything reported by dmesg when you tried to force the mount? - remember to add both your comment and anything else to your question.

Comment: I think it is ext3. sdc1 was already mounted. Should I choose some other destination instead? `/dev/sdc1 already mounted`

Comment: not sure that I understand - when you plug in the drive, does it mount to /dev/sdc1?  In that case you should see it mount in nautilus - alternatively umount /dev/sdc1 and mount as per my answer - obviously change ext4 to ext3.

Comment: I had another drive already mounted to /dev/sdc1. I also have a 500 GB WD disk that mounts with no probblem (FAT filesystem). But I still can't mount the 1 TB drive neither with Ubuntu not Windows. I'll carefully try again but this is what I get: `$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdc1 /media/LaCie -o force
mount: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or /media/LaCie busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is mounted on /media/My Book` or `mount: special device /dev/sdc1 does not exist` since some of the output above refers to the WD drive that I now disconnected.

Comment: ok - if something else is mounted to /dev/sdc1 then you'll need to find the device it is trying to mount as now - previously in your question you ran dmesg | tail - what is it trying to mount now?  /dev/sdd1 ??

Comment: Thank you for the help. I ran dmesg | tail and nothing relevant appeared. I rebotted, tried live bott to another ubuntu version (10.04) and still no sign of the drive since the stuff I pasted was from the WD 500 GB and the drive I'm trying to get started is a 1 TB LaCie..It's like it isn't turned on but the light is on and the cables are proerly connected and it wan't physically damaged and used to work..What could be the problem?

Comment: Niklas - if you first boot without your drive - run dmesg - plug in your drive and run dmesg again.  If no output is displayed - then my strong guess is that you have a defective drive.

Comment: OK fossfreedom it doesn't appear in Windows either so I wonder what could've happened. Thanks for the help anyway and I'll update if I reach some conclusion what is up with the drive.

Comment: I've updated my answer with our findings so far.

Answer (score 2):

Can you mount it manually? Run

```
dmesg | tail
```

Find out which drive it's using. Then:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Replacing the /dev/sdXY with what ever port it is.

EDIT:

Run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

Then:

```
cd ls /mnt
```

Comment: I tried running `dmesg`and got some mysterious output I pasted above

Comment: Plug in the drive and immediately run that command.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran the command but couldn't dedoce the output. It's pasted above.